# KeystoneJS can't logged admin UI by the generated password

Tags: keystonejs

I am running KeystoneJS app locally by `docker-compose` and mongodb.

After I run `docker-compose up` to start the application, all goes well, I can acess the link by
**http://localhost:3000/admin**, 
but I can't log in by the generated password:

```
✔ Connected to database
my-admin | - Preparing to accept requests
my-admin | 
my-admin | 
my-admin | User created:
my-admin |   email: admin@example.com
my-admin |   password: 30d234be8ee9
my-admin | Please change these details after initial login.
my-admin | 
my-admin | ✔ Keystone instance is ready at http://localhost:3000 
my-admin |  Keystone Admin UI:    http://localhost:3000/admin
my-admin |  GraphQL API:      http://localhost:3000/admin/api
```

After press the sign in, there are 3 requests:

POST 200
GET 304
GET 304

Here is the log:

```
| {"level":30,"time":1576853673666,"pid":36,"hostname":"5759ebc8fe99","req":{"id":50,"method":"GET","url":"/__webpack_hmr","headers":{"host":"localhost:3000","connection":"keep-alive","accept":"text/event-stream","cache-control":"no-cache","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","referer":"http://localhost:3000/admin/users?fields=_label_%2Cname%2Cemail%2CisAdmin","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"},"remoteAddress":"::ffff:172.20.0.1","remotePort":34154},"res":{"statusCode":404,"headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","x-keystone-app-version":"1.0.0","vary":"Origin, Accept-Encoding","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","content-security-policy":"default-src 'none'","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":152}},"responseTime":1,"msg":"request completed","v":1}
```

And the generated password part should be from here

```
const initialiseData = require('./initial-data');
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Disable SSL works for local testing.

`secureCookies: false`